# For-Loop Notifications Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have set up a series of For-Loop generated links that are supposed to display customized messages in the form of a notification.

The function to display the notification is in my background event page (eventPage.js):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == "notification"){
        var notifOptions = {
            type: 'basic',
            iconUrl: 'icon48.png',
            title: request.ttl,
            message: request.msg
        };
        chrome.notifications.create('notti', notifOptions);
    }
});
```

Meanwhile, on the content page (content.js), there is are two conditions that link to this function:

---

First:

```
if (request.todo == "full"){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo: "notification", ttl: 'Title', msg: 'Test!'});
    }
```

This first function works, and the notification displays without any issues (thus, there are no problems with permissions etc.).

---

The second condition is the one that doesn't work:

```
 if(request.todo == "quick"){
        for (let i = 0; i < wrds.length; i++) {
            var entry = "#"+wrds[i];
            if ($(entry).length) {
                $(entry).on("click", function() {
                    var msg = prns[i]+'\n'+defs[i];
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo: "notification", ttl: 'Title', msg: msg});
                    alert(msg);
                }); 
            }
        }}
```

This condition tries to set up a series of notifications in the for loop. The thing is, while the alert works perfectly, the notification doesn't appear at all.

How do I get the for-loop generated notifications to appear?

Comment: Think about what an if statement is. It's checking to see if the conditions you provided it are true. With that in mind, what do you think is happening when you're passing it  if ($(entry).length) as an if statement. What is the data type of $(entry).length? Do you know how to use that datatype in a condition of a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop version doesn't work because the notification titles need to be unique.

In order to make it so that the notification will always appear, regardless of whether or not it has appeared before, a unique name needs to be used for its creation.

In order to solve this, I decided to have the name be a unique time stamp.

```
for (let i = 0; i < wrds.length; i++) {
            var entry = "#"+wrds[i];
            if ($(entry).length) {
                $(entry).on("click", function() {
                    var timestamp = String(new Date().getTime());
                    var msg = prns[i]+'\n'+defs[i];
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo: "notification", ttl: wrds[i], msg: msg, stamp:timestamp});
                }); 
            }
        }
```

---

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == "notification"){
        var notifOptions = {
            type: 'basic',
            iconUrl: 'icon48.png',
            title: request.ttl,
            message: request.msg
        };
        chrome.notifications.create(request.stamp, notifOptions);
    }
});
```